# Вопрос по грамотности оформления кода (JS, Регулярные выражения)

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, инспекция-кода

Добрый день!

Необходимо строку перевести в нижний регистр и удалить все кроме цифр и символов, вот рабочий код:

```
 var str = "Some_string-9"
 str=str.toLocaleLowerCase();
 str=str.replace(/\W/g, "");
 str=str.replace(/_/g, ""); 
 //result: somestring9
```

Грамотно ли оформлять его подобным образом? В смысле в три строки такую простую операцию, спасибо!

Comment: одно слово: вкусовщина

Comment: Ясно=) Я начинающий программист, интересно нет ли в этом коде грубой стилистической ошибки.

Comment: Как минимум, обе регулярки можно объединить `str.replace(/[\W_]/g, "").toLowerCase()`

Comment: @ЕвгенийМошкин всё, что не трудно читать и приятно глазу - не является ошибкой

Comment: У вас ошибка в постановке условия. Если убрать "все **кроме** цифр и символов", то  из `Some_string-9` получится `_-9`.

Answer (score 1):

Два ваших регулярных выражения можно запросто объединить в одно. В остальном - это все дело вкуса. Лично я написал бы вот так:

```
var str = 'Some_string-9';
var result = str.toLocaleLowerCase().replace(/[\W_]+/g, '');
```

Comment: `toLocaleLowerCase`, а потом удалить все нелатинские буквы.. ну а что? ))